# Poulan Pro leaf blower engine not sealed, and threads are broken, how can i fix this

Tags: small-engine, compression, seal, stripped-thread

I've been trying to get a `Poulan Pro leaf blower` engine to run. I had noticed that the seal for the engine isn't tight and I saw that the threads were stripped. I know compression is needed for combustion.

I tried using a simple thread restorer kit but it didn't hold. I tried a bigger thread creator, and now the original bolt is too small. (I was probably being an idiot and wasn't paying attention.) Does anyone know a way I can hopefully restore the seal and threads?

The model information on the cover is:

```
25cc Gas Blower
200mph
Bvm200FE
Poulan Pro
```

here is where the seal I'm referring to is:

[image: engine seal]
[image: zoomed out view of engine]

Comment: Which seal? Are you taking about the head bolts?

Comment: @the_storyteller i'm going to add some images so you can see what I'm talking about as I have no idea what most of the part names are.  I'm completely new to this stuff.

Comment: An indication of the size of the original bolts and the new thread diameter should be helpful

Comment: @Martin, I am unsure of the original bolt size and thread diameter, I am a noob at this stuff and I have no idea what i'm doing. Although I will try to get as much information as possible, I am still learning how to do this stuff so try and bear with me

Comment: Do you have a more zoomed-out picture too? I can't tell for sure what the thing in the upper half of the picture is.

Comment: @the_storyteller I added the picture you asked for. does that help?

Comment: Oh, yes, that gasket definitely needs to be tight. Each rotation of the engine, gas is sucked into that bottom half, squished super hard, and squirted under pressure into the top half. If the gasket isn't tight, it won't work, period.

I'd try to tap it with oversized dies (what it sounds like you did) and just find a different bolt in the large size to replace the original.

Comment: @the_storyteller i don't know why you didn't post that as an answer, but the issue with this is that the hole that does down to the threads i'm afraid of breaking the cooling fins, (at least that's what i think they're called)

Comment: Could you possibly get a bolt with a different shape of head? Something like a socket head cap screw, which uses an allen key might be able to fit where a hex head bolt wouldn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119344/discussion-between-zachary-cross-and-the-storyteller).

Comment: @the_storyteller can you please post your solution as an answer, I'd like to mark It as the answer but I'm unable to as you posted it as a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That gasket definitely needs to be tight. Each rotation of the engine, gas is sucked into that bottom half, squished super hard, and squirted under pressure into the top half. If the gasket isn't tight, it won't work, period.

I'd try to tap it with oversized dies (what it sounds like you did) and just find a different bolt in the large size to replace the original.

If the bolt won't fit down past the fins, could you possibly get a bolt with a different shape of head? Something like a socket head cap screw, which uses an allen key might be able to fit where a hex head bolt wouldn't.

[image: socket head cap screw]

Answer (score 0):

To get back to the original size a helicoil may work. BUT it depends on how much damage you have done which is unclear from the information you don’t supply.

It may be possible to repair more damage but that would mean a machine shop and welding etc.

And what leaf blower does 200mph?

Comment: i'll add some images so you can see

Comment: @SolarMike, looks like 200 mph is the wind speed it produces ... like an F5 hurricane. :)

Comment: @SolarMike, all I did was increase the diameter of the hole.